# PHP Remove Array Containing Empty Value within a Bigger, more complex Array

Tags: php, arrays, unset, array-filter

I know this might seem like a duplicate for other questions out there, but I've been testing the solutions for the other questions and I can't get them to work in my specific situation.

I have a "complex" multidimiensional array called `$get_food` that looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [dietID] => 562
            [blockNum] => 1
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [mealTitle] =>
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 1
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [mealTitle] =>
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 1
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [dietID] => 562
            [blockNum] => 2
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [mealTitle] => Carnitas
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 1
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [mealTitle] => Geometry
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 1
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] => 21
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [dietID] => 562
            [blockNum] => 3
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [mealTitle] => Carburation
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 1
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
                [2] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 2
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
                [3] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 3
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
                [4] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 4
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
                [5] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 5
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                    [mealTitle] => Bar Rescue
                )
                [1] => Array (
                    [foodNumber] => 1
                    [portions] => 1
                    [foodID] =>
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I need to iterate thru it and remove the sub arrays that have an empty `[foodID]`.

e.g. Remove the whole sub-array with the key `[5]` because it has an empty `[foodID]` item and it's useless that way:

```
[5] => Array (
    [foodNumber] => 5
    [portions] => 1
    [foodID] =>
)
```

And once those sub arrays are deleted, I need to reconstruct the main array so it looks the same than it did originally (with the same levels), but without the unwanted sub-arrays.

I managed to do this on a much simpler multidimensional array, but not this time around. I can't get it to look the same at the end.

This is the messy code post-frustration that I have right now that just outputs nonsense:

```
foreach($get_food as $key => $meal):    
    foreach($meal as $key1 => $mealpart){
        foreach($mealpart as $key2 => $food){
            //print_r($food);

            foreach($food as $key3 => $fooditem){
                if(($key3 != 0)&&($get_food[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3]['foodID'] == '')){

                    unset($get_food[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3]);

                    //echo 'No Food ID';
                } else {
                    $updatedFood[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3]= $fooditem;
                }   
            }

        }

    }       endforeach;
```

So, any help is very much appreciated :)

//////// EDIT

The main array is put together from 8 arrays.
Here's the `var_export` for them together as one:

```
$get_food = array(
0 => array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            'dietID' => '562',
            'blockNum' => '1',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '33',
                ) ,
            ) ,
            1 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '30',
                ) ,
            ) ,
            2 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '34',
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
) ,
1 => array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            'dietID' => '562',
            'blockNum' => '2',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '',
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
) ,
2 => array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            'dietID' => '562',
            'blockNum' => '3',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '',
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
) ,
3 => array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            'dietID' => '562',
            'blockNum' => '4',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '',
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
) ,
4 => array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            'dietID' => '562',
            'blockNum' => '5',
        ) ,
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                0 => array(
                    'mealTitle' => '',
                ) ,
                1 => array(
                    'foodNumber' => '1',
                    'portions' => '1',
                    'foodID' => '',
                ) ,
            ) ,
        ) ,
    ) ,
) ,
5 => array(
    0 => '',
) ,
6 => array(
    0 => '',
) ,
7 => array(
    0 => '',
) ,
```

);

///// EDIT 2

**////////////////// SOLUTION ////////////////////**

Thanks to @Brian 's help, who made me realize I was targeting the wrong keys and that I was trying to create an additional array that was not necessary I came up with the solution to this issue.

You can see the working code here:
http://codepad.org/6xgrpo46

Hope this helps someone in the future! :)

Comment: It would be more helpful to post your array in a testable form (`var_export`). We can't test our answers with vardumps!

Comment: @thg435 Thank you for noting that! I've added the `var_export` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking if the foodID is empty or not, you are looking at the wrong value:

```
$get_food[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3]['foodID']
```

vs.

```
$get_food[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3][1]['foodID']
```

And the same problem seems to be for the `unset` in your example.

```
foreach($get_food as $key => $meal){
    foreach($meal as $key1 => $mealpart){
        foreach($mealpart as $key2 => $food){
            foreach($food as $key3 => $fooditem){
                if ($key3 == 0)
                    continue;
                if (empty($get_food[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3][1]['foodID']))
                    unset($get_food[$key][$key1][$key2][$key3][1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah! It was targeting the wrong key. That unsets the empty element. But how do I output the updated array?

Comment: I'm not so sure what you mean here. `$get_food` was mutated by running  through the array using foreach and using `unset` on one of its members. Just access it with `$get_food`. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I edited the question with my results. I'm pretty sure it's my mistake, but I can't figure out what is it exactly :(

Comment: It was working on the exact array that you gave (from var_export), here: http://codepad.org/NTyfm5vB -- can you double check that the layout of `$get_food` matches?

Comment: The output still has sub-arrays with empty `[foodID]` elements.

Comment: I managed to make it work! It was still a matter of targeting the wrong key. Here you can see the working code: http://codepad.org/6xgrpo46    // Thank you a lot for your help! :)